# Убрать белую обводку на подсказке в яндекс карте и поставить другой балун при клике

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Вот инициализация яндекс карты

```
                 ymaps.ready(function () {
                                    myMap = new ymaps.Map("YMaps", {
                                        center: [55.76, 37.64],
                                        zoom: 10
                                    });
                                    // Создаем коллекцию геообъектов.
                                    var myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
                                    // Добавляем метки в коллекцию.
                                    myCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark([37.61, 55.75], { 
                                        balloonContent: '<div class="mark_desc"><h3>Заголовок / Название объекта</h3>'+
                                                                '<p class="p_1"><b>г. Москва, ул. Тухачевского, 60</b></p>'+
                                                                '<p>Клубный комплекс из двух домов, расположен вблизи..</p>'+
                                                                '<div class="mark_link_wrapp"><i class="globus"></i><a class="yellow_link" href="#">Перейти на сайт объекта</a></div></div>',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        iconLayout: 'default#image',
                                        iconImageHref: 'img/map_mark.png',
                                        iconImageSize: [44, 51],
                                        iconImageOffset: [-44, -51],
                                    }));
                                    myCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark([30.30, 50.27], { 
                                        balloonContent: '<div class="mark_desc"><h3>Заголовок / Название объекта</h3>'+
                                                                '<p class="p_1"><b>г. Москва, ул. Тухачевского, 60</b></p>'+
                                                                '<p>Клубный комплекс из двух домов, расположен вблизи..</p>'+
                                                                '<div class="mark_link_wrapp"><i class="globus"></i><a class="yellow_link" href="#">Перейти на сайт объекта</a></div></div>',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        iconLayout: 'default#image',
                                        iconImageHref: 'img/map_mark.png',
                                        iconImageSize: [44, 51],
                                        iconImageOffset: [-44, -51],
                                    }));

                                    // Добавляем коллекцию на карту.
                                    myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);
                                    // Устанавливаем карте центр и масштаб так, чтобы охватить коллекцию целиком.
                                    myMap.setBounds(myCollection.getBounds());

                                    myMap.controls.remove('geolocationControl');
                                    myMap.controls.remove('searchControl');
                                    myMap.controls.remove('trafficControl');
                                    myMap.controls.remove('typeSelector');
                                    myMap.controls.remove('fullscreenControl');
                                    myMap.controls.remove('rulerControl');
                                    myMap.controls.remove('zoomControl');
                                    myMap.behaviors.disable(['scrollZoom']);

                                });
```

При клике на балун получается так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть нужно убрать белую обводку. И при клике на балун заменить его на другой черный с желтым. Как это сделать?

Comment: У вас же создается <div class="mark_desc"> ... вот к нему наверно и привязаны бордер и тень. В CSS пробуйте тестить `.mark_desc {border: 2px solid red; box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px blue;}` — А потом уже можно играться с цветами, если прокатит. Или... наводите курсор на рамку, правый клик мышки → В открывшемся меню последний пункт "Inspect" (посмотреть код). Можно открыть и копаться...

Comment: mark_desc катомизирован, но белую обводку задает сама яндекс карта вот ее нужно убрать. То есть mark_desc находится внутри обводки яндекс карты

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать свой собственный макет балуна. Тут релевантный пример в песочнице: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan